# Mock an attribute within an HttpServlet through the WebApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, servlets

Suppose I have an `HttpServlet` with an attribute (`MyAttribute`). I want to replace the latter with a mock, after the servlet has been initialized.

I'm instantiating my attribute in the overridden `MyServlet.init()` method like this:

```
WebApplicationContext wac = getWebApplicationContext();
this.myAttribute = (MyAttribute) wac.getBean("myAttribute");
```

Now, in my unit test all I got is a `WebApplicationContext` object.<sup>1</sup>

I planned mocking the attribute like this:

```
MyServlet myServlet = (MyServlet) WebApplicationContext.getServletContext().getServlet("myServlet");
myServlet.setMyAttribute(EasyMock.createStrictMock(MyAttribute.class));
```

Unfortunately, the `ServletContext().getServlet()` method is deprecated, currently returns always `null` and will be permanently removed in future versions. Hence my question:

**How to mock an attribute of an HttpServlet through a WebApplicationContext?**

<sup>1:</sup> This is due to my unit test starting a Tomcat'ish Server instance in an own thread returning me the WebApplicationContext of my application after it's up and running.

Comment: You want to fill an attribute in a Servlet? If this servlet attribute is a plain field in your servlet and it can be instantiated several times in the life cycle of the servlet, then looks like a design issue in your servlet class. I would recommend setting the attribute in session or passing the data as request parameter instead, depending on your needs.

Comment: No, actually the Servlet delegates work to another class `MyAttribute`. I want to exchange the instance of this class with a mocked one.

Comment: Again, if you have this `myAttribute` as a field in the servlet that can be initialized anytime in the lifecycle of the servlet, then you have a design issue. You should use another mechanism like a servlet init parameter instead.

Comment: `myAttribute` is a bean which gets initialized only once. Also, the field `myAttribute` itself gets initialized only once in the overridden `init()`-method of the Servlet. This is hardly anytime in the lifecycle.